# JwtFormat: why does it add the token's issuer to the ValidIssuers property?

Tags: oauth, jwt, owin, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I'm taking a look at the source code of the JwtFormat class and I'm wondering why does it add the Issuer it recovers from the token to the list of ValidIssuers. Does that mean that it will accept all issuers as valid if I don't specify a key or provide a IssueValidator handler to the TokenValidationParameters that are being used?

Btw, I'm lookit at this class because I'm investigating an issue regarding the use of JWT tokens (azure ad v2.0) in a web api app that seems to be ignoring the ValidIssuer property:

```cs
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions {
      AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
         GetTokenValidationParameters(),
         new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(authority)),
         Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider {
           OnValidateIdentity = ValidateIdentity
         }
 });

private TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameters() {
    return new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidAudience = ConfigData.ClientId,
        ValidIssuer = "nobody",
        ValidIssuers = null,
        IssuerValidator = ValidateIssuer
    };
}
```

**I'm editing this to give more information about what's going on.**

According to the source code, ValidateIssuer is true by default, so there's no need to set it again. Just to be sure, here's the source code:

```
public TokenValidationParameters()
{
  this.RequireExpirationTime = true;
  this.RequireSignedTokens = true;
  this.SaveSigninToken = false;
  this.ValidateActor = false;
  this.ValidateAudience = true;
  this.ValidateIssuer = true;
  this.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false;
  this.ValidateLifetime = true;
}
```

I'm setting up the IssuerValidator because I want to make sure that if the ValidIssuer is set, then I want to compare the token's issuer with that value (and don't want to check against the ValidIssuers collection when the ValidIssuer's validation fails).

In case you're wondering where the ValidIssuers is being filled (and yes, even in my example, it's being automatically populated, even though I've set it explicityl to null), it's happening in JwtFormat's Unprotect method:

```
public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(protectedText))
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (protectedText));
  if (!(this.TokenHandler.ReadToken(protectedText) is JwtSecurityToken))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof (protectedText), Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.Properties.Resources.Exception_InvalidJwt);
  TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = this._validationParameters;
  if (this._issuerCredentialProviders != null)
  {
    validationParameters = validationParameters.Clone();
    IEnumerable<string> second1 = this._issuerCredentialProviders.Select<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider, string>((Func<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider, string>) (provider => provider.Issuer));
    validationParameters.ValidIssuers = validationParameters.ValidIssuers != null ? validationParameters.ValidIssuers.Concat<string>(second1) : second1;
    IEnumerable<SecurityToken> second2 = this._issuerCredentialProviders.Select<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider, IEnumerable<SecurityToken>>((Func<IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider, IEnumerable<SecurityToken>>) (provider => provider.SecurityTokens)).Aggregate<IEnumerable<SecurityToken>>((Func<IEnumerable<SecurityToken>, IEnumerable<SecurityToken>, IEnumerable<SecurityToken>>) ((left, right) => left.Concat<SecurityToken>(right)));
    validationParameters.IssuerSigningTokens = validationParameters.IssuerSigningTokens != null ? validationParameters.IssuerSigningTokens.Concat<SecurityToken>(second2) : second2;
  }
  SecurityToken validatedToken;
  ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity) this.TokenHandler.ValidateToken(protectedText, validationParameters, out validatedToken).Identity;
  AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
  if (this.UseTokenLifetime)
  {
    DateTime validFrom = validatedToken.ValidFrom;
    if (validFrom != DateTime.MinValue)
      properties.IssuedUtc = new DateTimeOffset?((DateTimeOffset) validFrom.ToUniversalTime());
    DateTime validTo = validatedToken.ValidTo;
    if (validTo != DateTime.MinValue)
      properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset?((DateTimeOffset) validTo.ToUniversalTime());
    properties.AllowRefresh = new bool?(false);
  }
  return new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
}
```

Btw, this method ends up being called (indirectly) by the AuthenticateCoreAsync method when it needs to deserialize the token:

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
{
  try
  {
    string requestToken = (string) null;
    string authorization = this.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      requestToken = authorization.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
    OAuthRequestTokenContext requestTokenContext = new OAuthRequestTokenContext(this.Context, requestToken);
    await this.Options.Provider.RequestToken(requestTokenContext);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTokenContext.Token))
      return (AuthenticationTicket) null;
    AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext tokenReceiveContext = new AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext(this.Context, this.Options.AccessTokenFormat, requestTokenContext.Token);
    await this.Options.AccessTokenProvider.ReceiveAsync(tokenReceiveContext);
    if (tokenReceiveContext.Ticket == null)
      tokenReceiveContext.DeserializeTicket(tokenReceiveContext.Token);
//remaining code removed
}
```

Since I really haven't read the specs, I was wondering if anyone could explain me this behavior (of always adding the token's issuer to the ValidIssuers collection and checking if the token's issuer is in the ValidIssuers - which will always be true!)

**Final edit**

Ok, my bad...Not enough coffee, I think...In fact, the issuer is being added not from the token itself, but from the IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider that is passed to the JwtFormat ctor (gets it from the metadata endpoint)...

Sorry guys...

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: Did you set validateIssuer to true in your TokenValidationProperties?

Comment: Can you provide a URL for the source code you are reviewing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently without Vs, because I'm writing on my mobile phone, there should be a ValidateIssuer Property in the TokenValidationParameters, but it looks like you set the IssuerValidator to ValidateIssuer, which should be true, so try it that way:

```
private TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameters() {
    return new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidAudience = ConfigData.ClientId,
            ValidIssuer = "nobody",
            ValidateIssuer = true
    };
}
```

Comment: Hello Nikolaus. Yes, there is, and it's true by default (that's why I'm not setting it). I've set the IssueValidator so that I could copy/paste the default authentication code and see why changing the ValidIssuer was not disallowing the token. That's how I've found the "issue" I've mentioned in the quesiton...

Comment: @LuisAbreu But your Code seems to set the IssueValidator to ValidateIssuer, that means by convention true. Then your Code sets the issue, isn't it?

Comment: I've updated the post with more info. What I don't understand is why the token's issuer is always added to the ValidIssuers collection and why does the default IssueValidator method will always check the issuer against the ValidIssuers collection when you set the ValidIssuer property (this will always return true because the token's issuer ends up being added to the ValidIssuers collection!). Thanks